# Visual Studio, best way to compile directly to Program Files (access denied issues)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, permissions

I have some problems compiling my solution directly to Program Files since the folder is protected in Windows.

I've tried to compile to bin\Release in the project folder and the do a COPY using post build events but still I'm getting access denied problems.

I've been able to get around the problem by starting Visual Studio as an Administrator, but I'm not satisfied doing that.

Do you have any suggestions on how to do this without starting Visual Studio as an Administrator?

Comment: Assign write permissions to the folder to your account.

Comment: Don't do that. The folder is protected for a good reason. If you want your files visible in program files, create a hard link to your regular build directory from Program Files (use `ln` command at the prompt).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I need to do it to simplify the testing, i'm building a class library which is then used by an installed software and to be able to test it I need it to be in the correct folder under Program Files. 'ln' does not seem to exist in my enviroment? Got any more information on "hard links"?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, let me ask - I'm curious - why not? I agreed that 'program files' are protected for a good reason and changing permissions for main folder is not recommended... But why we should not set permissions as we need for our folder inside of 'program files' ?

Comment: @Dario Sorry, I meant [mklink](http://superuser.com/q/255731/133310).

Comment: I doubt creating a symlink is any better from security point of view. With a write permission, you can get any stuff to appear under Program files. With a symlink, you can do that same thing, it's just you're writing to another folder. I can't see a benefit.

Comment: @Dario There is no protection if you run an exe yourself. There is a protection in that malware cannot inject its libraries into a legitimate app's folder. See e.g. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130705-00/?p=3883/ and follow the links from there.

Comment: This question makes absolutely no sense, and reflects an astonishing level of confusion. You want to have read-write access to system directories, but you're "unsatisfied" with running Visual Studio with administrative privileges? That *is* how you grant yourself read-write access to system directories.

Comment: @CodyGray: I'm just trying to understand this better and you're welcome to clarify things. In older versions of windows there was no protection on these folders...

Comment: Yeah, in Windows 9x there was no protection on these folders. Gotta go back *at least* 15 years (for consumer versions, much longer in a practical sense since all versions of Windows NT have used this security model). Surely you've upgraded once or twice since the 16-bit days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up running Visual Studio as an administrator. That was the simplest solution for me. Thanks everybody that contributed.

Answer (score 0):

Just setup permissions for your Windows User for target folder on 'Security' tab (visible only in Windows Pro) - add write (or full control) permissions.

In both case be sure that your Windows User is not included to any group with restricted access to target (or his parent) folder. 'Deny' permissions are higher priority than 'Allow' permission.

*(Also you can write post-build script to copy only nesesery files from bin to program files, but still you must have write permission like described above).*

Answer (score 0):

Just provide **privilege** to that **specific folder** from **windows administrator accounts** in which user account are you running your project into visual studio project then it should start to work.